# Predictions in a system in which (almost) all regressors are endogenous

Tags: least-squares, prediction, networks

Consider the following system where all variables are endogenous.

\begin{align*}
x_{1}  &  =\beta_{21}x_{2}+\beta_{31}x_{3}+u_{1}\\
x_{2}  &  =\beta_{12}x_{1}+\beta_{32}x_{3}+u_{2}\\
x_{3}  &  =\beta_{13}x_{1}+\beta_{23}x_{2}+u_{3}%
\end{align*}

The $u$'s are error terms. There are no instruments available. With all
regressors endogenous, the $\beta$'s will be biased when estimated by OLS,
however, I am only interested in prediction. That is, I need to know how the
variables change, when the $u$'s change.

Rewriting the system in matrix notation and solving for the $x$ vector gives

\begin{align*}
\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}%
\end{array}
\right)  =\left(  \left(
\begin{array}
[c]{ccc}%
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)  -\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{ccc}%
0 & \beta_{21} & \beta_{31}\\
\beta_{12} & 0 & \beta_{32}\\
\beta_{13} & \beta_{23} & 0
\end{array}
\right)  \right)  ^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
u_{1}\\
u_{2}\\
u_{3}%
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align*}

***Questions***:

1. What would be wrong with simply estimating the system by OLS (equation
   by equation)?
2. Is there an alternative approach that allows us to study how the $u$'s
   affect the $x$'s?

---

**Edit**: I tried to keep the question as simple as possible, but now I think I
have to give more information. There is a
[follow-up question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501441) asking about inference. The follow-up question also gives some more context.

For each $x_{k}$ there are $T\times S$ observations ($S$ is the number of
species and $T$ is days). When estimating by OLS (for each $k$ separately), the regression equation is
$$
x_{k,s,t}=\sum_{k=1,k\not =l}\beta_{lk}x_{l,s,t}+\delta_{k,s}+\varepsilon
_{k,s,t}%
$$
where $\delta_{k,s}$ is a $k$-$s$-fixed-effect and $\varepsilon_{k,s,t}$ the residual.

Answer (score 1):

> Predictions in a system in which (almost) all regressors are
> endogenous

If you are interested in prediction only, endogeneity is not the core problem, while overfitting is. Read here: [Endogeneity in forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202278/endogeneity-in-forecasting/271993#271993)

Moreover

> What would be wrong with simply estimating the system by OLS (equation
> by equation)?

If you are focusing on prediction only, *equation by equation* is good; systems can be avoided.

Your second question

> Is there an alternative approach that allows us to study how the u's
> affect the $x$'s?

seems more focused on causal questions. Like manageable with Structural VARs

Comment: Thanks! +1 Your link which in turn is linked to Francis Diebold's discussion about T-consistency and P-constistency is extremely helpful.