# Inference in a system in which (almost) all regressors are endogenous

Tags: regression, correlation, inference, least-squares, networks

We conducted a number of tests on individual species over a period of several
days. Let $x_{k,s,t}$ denote the result of test $k$ for species $s$ at time
$t$. In total there are $S$ species, $K$ tests, and $T$ days.

We are interested in how the tests relate to each other. For example: Do
species that are good in test $k=1$, tend to be good in test $k=2$ as well?
You may think of the $K\times K$ relationships as a network connecting all tests.

We started out calculating Pearson correlations to construct a $K\times K$
correlation matrix. But since simple correlations confound direct and indirect
associations, we are thinking about running multiple regressions of the form
$$
x_{k,s,t}=\sum_{k=1,k\not =l}^{K}\beta_{lk}x_{l,s,t}+\delta_{k,s}%
+\varepsilon_{k,s,t}%
$$
where $\delta_{k,s}$ is a test-species fixed-effect and $\varepsilon
_{k,s,t}$ the residual. There are $K$ regression that we estimate separately by OLS. We have $K<<T\times S$. An obvious problem here is
that the regressors (except for the fixed effects) are endogenous. The use of
instrumental variables is not possible here.

Our main **question** is whether in this case multiple regressions can be justified over the use
of simple correlations. Stated differently, is the endogeneity problem large
enough to prohibit this approach here?

This is a follow-up question of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501278) which is about prediction.